# Next Js and wordpress header issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js

We have a website on Next.js the website is example.com

Then we have created a subfolder example.com/blog and installed WordPress to manage our blogposts.

Now I want to show same header or navigation on our example.com/blog from our main website example.com

What should we do?

Can I any one help?

I have tried it by editing header.php and function php. But still unable to resolve the issue.